# Split a large React application in smaller modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, frontend

**The problem**

I am currently working on a large React application, which has approximately 10,000 lines of code (and growing steadily). The large number of components is starting to become confusing, and I would like to split the application into multiple individual "modules".

The following is a (very simplified) version of the project structure:

```
.
└── src/
    ├── Components/
    │   ├── A/
    │   │   ├── A.tsx
    │   │   └── ...many child components that are only used here...
    │   ├── B/
    │   │   ├── B.tsx
    │   │   └── ...many child components that are only used here...
    │   └── C/
    │       ├── C.tsx
    │       └── ...many child components that are only used here...
    └── App.tsx
```

I am looking for a way to isolate the content of the `A`, `B`, and `C` directories so that they only export the parent component - while the children themselves are hidden from the other packages. However, I would like to share certain files among all of the projects, such as the `package.json` and the `/public` directory.

I do not need the "modules" to be individually deployable.

**The Java equivalent of the solution**

One example of something that would solve my issue is Java's concept of package-private visibility; however, I could not find anything similar in JavaScript/Typescript. This would allow me to declare `A.tsx`, `B.tsx`, and `C.tsx` as *public*, while keeping all of their children *package-private* - therefore being only accessible from within their "module".

Another example of something that would solve my issue is Java's concept of Maven modules, but just like the previous example, I could not find anything similar in JavaScript/Typescript. This would allow me to treat `A`, `B`, and `C` as sealed modules, allowing me to split the application into multiple logical pieces.

**The motivation**

- I struggle with separating concerns in the front-end as I do in the back-end. The concept of Maven modules really helps in organising the project in a cleaner way.
- I really do not like how every component is allowed to access any component in the project. This causes confusion and makes it much easier to introduce bugs.
- I would like to give my child components sensible names without polluting the namespace. For example, I want to name my components without appending the "module" name to their name, such as `AFoo.tsx`, `BFoo.tsx` and `CFoo.tsx`. If each child was only accessible from within its own "module", then they could all be named `Foo.tsx`, and there would be no way to import the wrong one.
- I would like to get *actually* useful suggestions from my IDE when auto-completing a component name. Since the IDE keeps suggesting components that are in other "modules", I have to manually type the first few letters of the name - which always include the name of the "module" - causing the list of imports to show virtually every existing component in the "module".

I would be grateful if anyone could point me to the JavaScript/Typescript way of achieving this. It does not have to be necessarily identical to the Java examples I gave above, as long as they achieve the same thing.

Thank you in advance.

**Extra information**

Should it help, the project uses the following:

- React 18.2.0
- Typescript 4.7.2
- Yarn as a package manager

Other:

- I tried using [dependency-cruiser](https://github.com/sverweij/dependency-cruiser), and while it is a very useful tool, it does not solve all of the issues I outlined above.

Comment: There is no such thing as `package private` in TS/JS. One thing you could do is to use `dependency cruiser` which disallows per rule to import component `Foo` from module B outside of the module. Besides, did you look into extracting these modules into npm packages which are just added to the project, I guess thats the best way to separate concerns?

Comment: Thank you @r3dst0rm, dependency cruiser was very helpful. However, it does not address some of the points above - such as the IDE issues. Regarding the NPM packages, may I please ask what you mean exactly?

Comment: *"I really do not like how every component is allowed to access any component in the project"* - it'd prove to be difficult to achieve in any trivial way as long as you used typescript. you might down to coding style guideline (in conjuction to dependency cruiser) to prefix all modules so you can hint the IDE with those prefixes when typing. i have no better idea than this ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Gimmi What I meant by this is for example, if you have a private NPM repo you could publish package `A`, `B` and `C` to it. And import each of them in their respective directory. This hides the child components but depends on how the components are set up. Another thing, the commonly used code could be another NPM package, rather than just a directory.

Comment: I don't see why you can't have several `Foo.tsx` components in your project? If you `import { Foo } from "./A/Foo.tsx"` then your IDE will use A.Foo for code completion and ignore B.Foo and C.Foo...